# Change Unicorn worker_process depending on env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I have a unicorn.rb file and I would like to set worker_process depending on the environment variable. I've tried the following approach without success:

```
environment = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
# Save on RAM while in development
if environment == 'development'
  worker_processes 1
else
  worker_processes 4
end
```

When I use `foreman start` I get the following error:

```
21:07:49 web.1    | /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:74:in `instance_eval': ./unicorn.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
21:07:49 web.1    | ./unicorn.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting $end
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:74:in `reload'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:67:in `initialize'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:104:in `new'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:104:in `initialize'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `new'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `load'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in `<main>'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
21:07:49 web.1    |     from /home/hg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@px/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
21:07:49 web.1    | exited with code 1
21:07:49 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Could I please get a pointer at how I can resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this this whole unicorn.rb file? Can you paste it fully or gist it or confirm that it is indeed full? I see that it is complaining about : on line 4 which i can't make out. First suggestion would be to avoid environment as a variable as it might be internally used in unicorn perhaps?

Comment: Here's my complete [gist file](https://gist.github.com/4633113). What's weird is that now that I try it again, it's working.

Comment: I suspect you might have left a : in there by mistake. :) Using vi/vim?

Comment: Yeah I did. And yes vim probably played a role. Thanks for the help @AdityaSanghi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was a mistake on my part and I suspect removing `:` solved it for me. However, for anyone looking for adjusting unicorn's worker_processes because they're RAM constrained in their development environment, here is my `unicorn.rb` file:

```
environment = ENV['RACK_ENV'] || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'

# Save on RAM while in development
if environment == 'development'
  worker_processes 1
else
  worker_processes 4
end

timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Close all open connections
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  @resque_pid ||= spawn("bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUES=fast")
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Reopen all connections
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

https://gist.github.com/4633113

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in doing this, I used a more host specific approach that allows machine specific unicorn processes with a hard coded default.

```
ENV['UNICORN_PROCESSES'] ||= '4'
worker_processes ENV['UNICORN_PROCESSES'].to_i
```